# Increasing size of a root EBS volume: stop or reboot instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, filesystems, partition, amazon-ebs

I am increasing the size of a root EBS volume for EC2's t2.medium instance. The instance is ruled by Ubuntu 14.04 AMI. I have read an official guide and found that to increase root partition size one needs to stop the instance and detach the EBS volume.

However, I was able to resize the volume without instance stop, just because I scheduled changes to be applied on reboot(and scheduled `fsck` on reboot too). Changes were done by `parted` program and included the destruction of existing volume and creation of the bigger one.

My question: was it a correct way to resize root partition? Could this way bring issues I haven't thought of?

Edit: `lsblk` output

```
$ lsblk 
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   128G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0     8G  0 part /
```

Comment: AWS documentation says restart is only required for previous generation instances. You appear to have used quite a different method from what the documentation says to do. Someone more experienced with Linux might be able to tell you whether it's ok or not. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the answer! Link that you added has a note deep below:`If the volume you are extending has been partitioned, you need to increase the size of the partition before you can resize the file system. You can also allocate additional partitions at this time. For more information, see Expanding a Linux Partition.` My volume is partitioned, will add info about that to the question.